# Having issues modifying javascript when create buttons that result in images showing up

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and would like to get some help and see where I'm making a mistake. Currently the javascript makes it so once you select both the "carrier" button and "capacity" button, the image of the iPhone shows up.

I've been trying to modify the javascript so you only need to click on the "carrier" button for the image of the iPhone to show up. I've spend hours trying to figure out a solution, but I've just started teaching myself how to code and have spend a lot of hours on this issue.

I appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Before selecting buttons:
[image]

After selecting buttons:
[image]

JS:

```
var selectedGB;
var selectedCarrier;
var displayCarrier;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.home-rt').hide();

$('.gb-button').each(function() {
$(this).click(function() {
$('.gb-button').removeClass('gb-button-selected');
console.log($(this).val());
selectedGB = $(this).val().slice(0,-2);
$(this).addClass('gb-button-selected');
                            updateCDisplay();
                        });
                    });
$('.carrier-button').each(function() {
$(this).click(function() {
$('.carrier-button').removeClass('carrier-button-selected');

$('.home-rt').hide();
if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-ATT') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'ATT';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Sprint') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Sprint';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Verizon') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Verizon';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Rogers') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Rogers';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Fido') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Fido';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Cricket') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Cricket';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Unlocked') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Unlocked';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-T-Mobile') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'TMobile';
                                    } else if ( $(this).hasClass('carrier-Wi-Fi') ) {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'WiFi';
                                    } else {
                                        selectedCarrier = 'Other';
                                    } 

                                    if (selectedCarrier == "ATT") {
                                        displayCarrier = "AT&T";
                                    } else {
                                    displayCarrier = selectedCarrier;
                                    }
                                $(this).addClass('carrier-button-selected');
                                updateCDisplay();
                            });
                        $('.price-button').each(function() {
                            $(this).click(function() {
                                $('.price-button').removeClass('price-button-selected');
                                selectedPrice = $(this).val();
                                $(this).addClass('price-button-selected');
                                updateCDisplay();
                            });
                        });

                    });
                });

                function updateCDisplay() {

                    $('.home-rt').hide();
                    if (selectedCarrier && selectedGB){

                                        $("#deviceLink").attr("href", "/sell/price/"+device+"/"+model+"/"+selectedCarrier+"/"+selectedGB);
                                        $("#deviceText").attr("href", "/sell/price/"+device+"/"+model+"/"+selectedCarrier+"/"+selectedGB);
                                        $("#deviceText").html(device + " " + model + "<br/>" + selectedGB + "GB" + " " + displayCarrier);
                                        $("#dealer").attr("action", "/sell/price/"+device+"/"+model+"/"+selectedCarrier+"/"+selectedGB);
                                        $("#private").attr("action", "/sell/private/"+device+"/"+model+"/"+selectedCarrier+"/"+selectedGB);
                                        $("#displayImage").attr("src", "images/specs_"+device+"_"+model+".jpg");
                                        $(".selectedView").show();
                    }
                }



<div style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0 20px 0;"><!---<img src="/images/test.jpg"/>-->
<div style="font-size:16px">Choose Your Carrier:</div>

<div><!--<input class="carrier-button carrier-all carrier-button-selected " type="button">--><input class="carrier-button carrier-ATT" type="button" /> <input class="carrier-button carrier-Verizon" type="button" /><input class="carrier-button carrier-Sprint" type="button" /> <input class="carrier-button carrier-T-Mobile" type="button" /> <input class="carrier-button carrier-Unlocked" type="button" /></div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0 20px 0;">
<div style="font-size:16px">Choose Your Capacity:</div>

<div>
<p><!--<input class="gb-button gb-button-selected " value="ALL" type="button">--><input class="gb-button" type="button" value="16GB" /> <input class="gb-button" type="button" value="32GB" /> <input class="gb-button" type="button" value="64GB" /></p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var device = "iPhone";
var model = "5S";
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/specs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where's the javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. Adding it right now

Comment: Just added it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `js/specs.js` it says:

`if (selectedCarrier && selectedGB){`

Try making it to:

`if (selectedCarrier)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much, I really appreciated it. You saved me so many headaches!